# What $APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD does?

Tags: apache2, systemd

I see in my `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`:

```
[Service]
...
Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
```

And while it is obviously true that Apache was started by systemd, I can't find any explanation for what is the actual effect of this environment variable.

Comment: I *think* it might be relevant for [mod_systemd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_systemd.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in `/usr/sbin/apachectl`:

```
# If running on systemd we should not start httpd without systemd
# or systemd will get confused about the status of httpd.
```